# Resizing curve by dragging control points

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, touch

I'm trying to resize a drawn quadCurve by dragging one of its 3 control points so the curve can fit. What is the best approach to do this? letting you know that I'm using an imageView for drawing. Not using drawRect.

I know that I should detect if the touch is on the control points which is pretty easy but I don't know what to do after in my touchMoved and touchEnded methods.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- I would not use an image view for this. This is the kind of problem that `drawRect:` is for.
- Don't use `touchesMoved`. Use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the control points.
- Make the control points subviews so you can attach gesture recognizers to them.
- To work well, the control points typically need to have a pretty large hit area (larger than they are visually). You can do this pretty easily by making the control point views larger than what they draw (so if they're drawn as a 13 point circle, you put that in the middle of a 23 point view).

For an example of code that does all this see [CurvyTextView.m](https://github.com/rnapier/ios5ptl/blob/master/ch18/CurvyText/CurvyText/CurvyTextView.m). It doesn't do the last point (the control point views are too small to use well on a real device). Ignore all the text drawing code. You just care about `updateControlPoints`, `addControlPoint:color:`, `initWithFrame:`, `pan:`, and `drawPath`.

Comment: Thanks for your tips but it seems to me it can be done in a simpler way. I just found [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/07/coregraphics-curves-and-lines-sample.html) and it's exactly what I want except that it's not meant for iOS. I tried adapting the code by using touch methods but have failed. What do you think?

Comment: UIPanGestureRecognizer is much simpler to implement than touchMoved (which is why Apple added gesture recognizers). Trying to convert OS X mouseDown to iOS touchMoved is basically rewriting it. If you prefer to not create subviews, then you can use a gesture recognizer on the main main and then hit test (which is how the mouseDown is implemented). Note also that my comments about the size of the hit-area are specific to mobile devices. On a Mac, the mouse is very precise. On mobile devices, you need to account for big fingers.

Comment: I understand now. One question though, what's the difference between P0 and P0_ ? because I need to change the controlPoints to what the user specifies (by tapping on the screen/finger drawing).

Comment: I directly accessed the ivars (which in this code have trailing underscores) in a couple of math routines that are called several thousand times. There should be a comment explaining it. Typically this should be self.P0 rather than accessing the ivar directly. I don't believe you need those routines; they're for manually calculating the Bézier.

Comment: yeah when I tried deleting them to see what happens, nothing was affected. The example was of great help thanks to you. I'm still having a problem sending the location of the controlPoints from a ViewController to this UIView. Is it because it's a UIView?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "sending the location." Make sure that when you modify the locations that you actually update the view's layout (call `updateControlPoints`)

Comment: Does the example that you've linked me to work for both iPad and iPhone or only iPad?